# Rotate bottom coordinates to be upside-down in print layout (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

Is it possible in QGIS (3.6) to somehow make all coordinates on the 4 sides of a map in a print layout point towards the map?

I found the option for the 2 vertical sides. If the map is rotated by 90° because of space and annotation issues, it would be nicer to have the bottom coordinates upside-down, pointing towards the map.

Then it wouldn't matter so much how the print out is rotated.

I thought of adding two grids, one for the bottom labels only. I can't find any option to rotate the labels independently of the orientation setting though.

Comment: It looks like there are only three possible orientations for the grid annotations: Horizontal, Vertical ascending and Vertical descending. There's no "horizontal upside-down" orientation. Even if you create a second grid there's no way to draw the annotations upside-down. The only workaround I can see is to create upside-down text boxes and manually enter the grid bottom coordinates into them.

Comment: That is actually not a bad workaround, not perfect but at least a good possibility :)